# convert byte array to uint numeric value

Tags: c#, byte, valueconverter, uint

Let's say I have array of bytes

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

I want to convert this array to get regular numeric variable of uint, so result will be

```
uint result = 12345;
```

So far all the example I've seen were with bytes, byte I don't need bytes, but numeric value.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
uint result = 0;
foreach (var digit in array)
{
    result = result * 10 + digit;
}
```

Or more fancily, using LINQ:

```
uint result = array.Aggregate((uint) 0, (curr, digit) => curr * 10 + digit);
```

Comment: Hey John, very important question, why is this works only for numbers until 10? If I will convert it from byte array 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 it will give me result 123456789, but if I will convert it from byte array 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 it will give me 1234567900 please need to know how to fix it?

Comment: @Stanislav: Well what did you *want* it to give? 10 isn't a digit. (This is why you really need to give clear requiremenst.)

Comment: well, got you right now... now know the mistake, thanks, was just a bit confused

Comment: but if you have quick answer on how to parse it if there is number higher than 9 and you can share would be great :)

Comment: A solution requires a problem. Maybe we should just ignore any values over 9. Maybe we should throw an exception. Maybe we should change it to a random number. Without requirements, it's impossible to suggest an implementation.